# Merging polygons interactively in ArcMap using less clicks than Merge tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, merge

I am looking for an interactive tool which simply merges two polygon geometries by clicking on each polygon and nothing else. I need a workflow for a particular project-step which cannot be automated due to the need to make visual checks of particular polygons.

I am in need of a way to merge 2 polygons together without having to do the following in ArcGIS:

- Select two Polygons
- open the Editing Toolbar
- initiate the Merge Tool
- Confirm which Polygon needs to be merged
- Press "Start"

This process in itself may only take 30 seconds, but is very inefficient if repeated 1000 times. I would simply like to know if there is a tool which can merge 2 polygons with only 2 mouse clicks. One click on the first polygon, one click on the second.

Comment: By "join" do you mean Merge or something else?  Can you **edit** your question to clarify, please?

Comment: -1. How do yiu want to merge 2 without first selecting them

Comment: The word *interactive* indicates that you want to have some input, yet you're saying that you don't want to have to do any work.. thus *non interactive*. You can dissolve polygons if that helps, that would remove any overlap but would destroy attributes. What are you hoping to achieve here? Can you draw a picture of an example so we can understand what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: By Interactive I mean that I want to only click on Polygon 1 and use a second click to click on polygon 2 - Both poylgons which be then merged into one. Attribute allocation is not an issue as they are all attributed the same.

Comment: Why did I get a minus point? Is there no assessement from an administrator regarding the allotment of minus points and if they are warrented?

Comment: No, everyone can give minus points and the administrator do not interfer with that (except if one user decides to systematically downvote all questions); Minus vote mean that someone considers that you did not search before asking, that your question is unclear, or that it is not useful. If you edit your question according to the comments, the user who gave you minus point (and only him) can decide to change his/her vote.

Comment: Could you tell why the merge function in the editing menu does not work in your case ?

Comment: The merge function DOES work in my case. The point of the question is to polish my workflow for a particular project. I am in need of a way to merge 2 polygons together without having to do the following in ArcGIS: Select 2 Polygons> Click on the Editing Toolbar and initiate the Merge Tool > Confirm which Polygon needs to be merged, and then Press "Start". This process in itself may only take 30 seconds...but is very inefficient if repeated.I would simply like to know if there is a tool which can merge 2 polygons with only 2 mouse clicks.One click on the first polygon, one click on the second.

Comment: A clarification such as this should be made as an **edit** to your question so that it can be re-opened. All relevant details should be placed in your question because there is no guarantee that potential answerers will read a comment trail.

Comment: If it is in the same layer, could you use the editor like this?: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m700000062000000

Comment: How should the attributes be handled? With the normal merge tool you are given a chance to select which feature the merged feature's attributes should come from. You'll have to decide if you want to always use the first or last feature, or some more complex handling of the attributes (sum, join, average, min, max, etc.). In any case, it sounds like you will need a custom tool for this. I think a Python add-in might work, but you'll need to do some R&D, unless someone's already made something available that matches your specific needs.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such out of the box tool, but it could probably be scripted to a custom button fairly easily. I've worked with similar in the past where first click selected a polygon and second click transferred attributes from the first to the second. This is pretty similar. You can also add the Merge tool as a button to a toolbar, eliminating the extra fractions of a second needed to pick it from the Editor dropdown. And if you don't need to pick which attributes to preserve, just hit enter as soon as you've activated the merge tool. Takes me less than 3 seconds per operation.